# Adding the sheetname to my dataframe as a variable

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, lapply

It works for the first df I do it for but then it says that it can't find the first sheet of the previous df in the second code (shown below)

Part that works:

```
H_Ambala <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sheets, function(X)
  transform(readxl::read_excel("/Users/emmawilliamson/Desktop/Haryana2010/Ambala.xlsx", sheet = X), Block = X)))
H_Ambala['District'] = 'Ambala'
View(H_Ambala)
```

Part that doesn't work:

```
H_Bhiwani['District'] = 'Bhiwani'
H_Bhiwani <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sheets, function(X)
  transform(readxl::read_excel("/Users/emmawilliamson/Desktop/Haryana2010/Bhiwani.xlsx", sheet = X), Block = X)))
View(H_Bhiwani)
```

> `Error: Sheet 'Block I' not found`

Comment: In the second example you overwrite `H_Bhiwani['District']` with the next line. Put it after the as in the first example.

Comment: It still says error block I not found, as in the part that doesn't work is referencing the sheet from the part that does work. Do you know why this is happening? Thanks for your help already x

Comment: The function looks at `sheets` and reads the names to get the sheet name. It does not find a sheet named "Block I". Have you checked the spreadsheet to see if there is a sheet named "Block I"?

Comment: There is a sheet in the first xlsx file, but not the second. I think it means that the Bhiwani code is still reading the sheets of Ambala, but I'm not sure why. Thanks again for your help!